# Line connecting footnotes and text using todonotes

Tags: footnotes, line, todonotes

As I don't know much (rather anything...) about the structure of how a document is set up in the background and if body and footnote area are absolutely separate entities, I have no idea if my wish is possible at all: I want to connect a note which I have in the footnotes with a certain word in the body with a line, using todonotes. Basically, I want notes which are displayed like inline notes where the footnotes are AND have them connected to the text like margin notes.

I have managed to make footnotes of inline notes, but when I try this with margin notes, the line connecting the note and the anchor is there, but the note is gone altogether. That's why I thought it may just not be possible to connect the body of the text with the footnote area at all...

Here's the MWE with inline notes as footnotes:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10, twoside=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[ruled]{manyfoot}
\usepackage[textsize=small,colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption=true]{todonotes} 

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalfont}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlyellow}[1]{{\sethlcolor{Goldenrod}\hl{#1}}}

\newcommand{\medium}[3][]{\hlyellow{#2}\todo[tickmarkheight=0.1cm, color=Goldenrod, #1]{#3}} %----> with this, I define a quick-to-type command for including my notes; in the original document, I have four of them, which is why I created a new command instead of re-definining the standard command; it takes three arguments: #1 is the (optional) title (inserted with the usual caption=), #2 are the words in the text to which the note applies, & #3 is the text of the actual note; thickmarkheight of course doesn't work here, as there is no line to display

\newfootnote{todos} %----> with the following code snippet, I define a new footnote type, as I still need default footnotes in my document and I don't want to have a mark here
\newcounter{footnotetodos}
\newcommand{\footnotetodos}{%
    \stepcounter{footnotetodos}%
    \Footnotemark\thefootnotetodos \Footnotetexttodos\thefootnotetodos}
\renewcommand{\thefootnotetodos}{}

\presetkeys%
{todonotes}%
{inline}
{noinlinepar}{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawInlineNote}{%
    \if@todonotes@dviStyle%
    {\if@todonotes@inlinepar\par\noindent\fi%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
            \draw node[inlinenotestyle] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \if@todonotes@inlinepar\par\fi}%
    \if@todonotes@authorgiven%
    {\noindent \@todonotes@useSizeCommand \@todonotes@author:\,\@todonotes@text}%
    \else%
    {\noindent \@todonotes@useSizeCommand \@todonotes@text}%
    \fi
    {\if@todonotes@inlinepar\par\noindent\fi%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
            \draw node[inlinenotestyle] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \if@todonotes@inlinepar\par\fi}%
    \else%
    {\if@todonotes@inlinepar\par\noindent\fi%
        \footnotetodos{{\hspace{-1.25em}} %---->this is the line I included to get the inline-to-dos into the footer with the newly created footnote type and to skip the indent usually reserved for the footnote mark(er)
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
                \draw node[inlinenotestyle,font=\@todonotes@useSizeCommand]{%
                    \if@todonotes@authorgiven%
                    {\noindent \@todonotes@author:\,\@todonotes@text}%
                    \else%
                    {\noindent \@todonotes@text}%
                    \fi};%
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
        \if@todonotes@inlinepar\par\fi}%
    \fi}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \listoftodos[To Dos for this document]
    \vspace{1cm}
    This is an example paragraph to showcase my use of the single to-do-note in the \medium[caption=This is the title]{footnotes}{This is the text of the note, not of the highlighted text.}. \blindtext
\end{document}
```

And here's a MWE with vanishing margin notes:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10, twoside=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[ruled]{manyfoot}
\usepackage[textsize=small,colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption=true]{todonotes} 

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalfont}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlyellow}[1]{{\sethlcolor{Goldenrod}\hl{#1}}}

\newcommand{\medium}[3][]{\hlyellow{#2}\todo[tickmarkheight=0.1cm, color=Goldenrod, #1]{#3}} %----> with this, I define a quick-to-type command for including my notes; in the original document, I have four of them, which is why I created a new command instead of re-definining the standard command; it takes three arguments: #1 is the (optional) title (inserted with the usual caption=), #2 are the words in the text to which the note applies, & #3 is the text of the actual note; thickmarkheight of course doesn't work here, as there is no line to display

\newfootnote{todos} %----> with the following code snippet, I define a new footnote type, as I still need default footnotes in my document and I don't want to have a mark here
\newcounter{footnotetodos}
\newcommand{\footnotetodos}{%
    \stepcounter{footnotetodos}%
    \Footnotemark\thefootnotetodos \Footnotetexttodos\thefootnotetodos}
\renewcommand{\thefootnotetodos}{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawMarginNote}{%
    \if@todonotes@dviStyle%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
        \draw node[notestyle] {};%
    \end{tikzpicture}\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\@todonotes@textwidth}%
        \if@todonotes@authorgiven%
        \@todonotes@useSizeCommand \@todonotes@author \@todonotes@text%
        \else%
        \@todonotes@useSizeCommand \@todonotes@text%
        \fi%
    \end{minipage}\\%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
        \draw node[notestyle] (inNote) {};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \else%
    \let\originalHbadness\hbadness%
    \hbadness 100000%
    \footnotetodos{ %----> This is where I want them to be treated as footnotes
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline=(X.base)]%
        \node(X){\vphantom{\@todonotes@useSizeCommand X}};%
        \if@todonotes@authorgiven%
        \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@useSizeCommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.north)%
        {\@todonotes@author};%
        \node(Y)[below=of X]{};%
        \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@useSizeCommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.south)%
        {\@todonotes@text};%
        \else%
        \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@useSizeCommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.north)%
        {\@todonotes@text};%
        \fi%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    \hbadness \originalHbadness%
    \fi}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \listoftodos[To Dos for this document]
    \vspace{1cm}
    This is an example paragraph to showcase my use of the single to-do-note in the \medium[caption=This is the title]{footnotes}{This is the text of the note, not of the highlighted text.}. \blindtext
\end{document}
```

The most elegant way would be to create a completely new command which is triggered by \usepackage[footnote]{todonotes} and which would be an exact copy of ALL inline notes commands + the footnote change. But as I don't need "real" inline notes, I thought this rather quick'n dirty solution would be enough.